# TypeScript Higher Kinded Types Alternative / Work Around

Tags: typescript

This is a snippet of a generic abstract class for creating HTTP resources for different APIs where the method's generic determines the response data, but the response wrapper around the data would preferably be controlled by the abstract class.

In the example `R` is the `SuccessResponse`, which depending on the API is a different response type wrapper for the response data `T`.

```
export abstract class AbstractApiResource<R> implements IApiResource {
  public get<T>(
    path: string,
    params: HttpParams = new HttpParams(),
    options: { [key: string]: any } = {}
  ): Observable<R<T>> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this._apiEndpoint}/${path}`, { params, observe: 'response', ...options })
      .pipe(this.handleResponse<T>());
}
```

Doing this shows an error indicating that `Type 'R' is not generic`, which makes since TypeScript has not implement [Higher Kinded Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but is there a work around to "accomplish" something similar to this in TypeScript?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone web IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) including expected uses (where `R` is specified in subclasses or something)?  My guess is that the closest you'll come to this is some hardcoded union of type constructors, but without something I can easily toy with it's hard to say.